# Wordpress permission denied while adding a submenu

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm facing a problem while creating a submenu under my settings menu n wordpress admin panel. I have done everything correctly and also I have the way to gt around this problem. But what i really want to know that why is the problem appearing.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'options_page');
function options_page() {

add_submenu_page(
        'options-general.php',
        'Options page',
        'Options page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-option-page',
        'option_config');   
    }
```

this works great and there is no problem with it. But when i tried to change 'my-option-page' to '`__FILE__`' it stops working saying that I don't have enough permission. I have this tutorial at http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-options-panel/
But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you logged in as administrator? Is the permission error from wordpress or the server?

Comment: yes. I'm developing a theme in my localhost using the id/pass i used while installing wp in my wamp

Comment: You should also be logged in to your Wordpress administrator account.

Comment: yes i'm logged in my wordpress as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Jaquith, a lead WordPress developer, tweeted in 2009 that "If you use **FILE** in add_submenu_page() or add_*_page() function calls in WordPress plugins, you’re doing it wrong. Use a unique string."

Is **FILE** already used for a menu or submenu?  That could be one cause; although of course I'd remove the use of **FILE** anyway.

Another cause could be that the first argument, "parent slug", doesn't exist as a menu page.  or if it does, it exists under a different name.